# Remove Easy Eaze/Easy In/Easy Out effect in Animation

Tags: animation

Good Evening

I'm trying to animate a moving mesh from one point to another.
Having added the key frames, I realised there is an easy in - easy out effect at the starting and ending of the animation. Similar to an effect I often used in Adobe AfterEffects. The mesh comes in slowly, moves fast and then ends slowly. How do I remove this effect from the animation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the interpolation will be bezier (round curve which will cause ease in and ease out) but if you want a linear interpolation, go into the *Dope Sheet* (or into the *Graph Editor*), select the keyframe then go into *Key > Interpolation Mode > Linear* (or shortcut <kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Also you can go into the *Edit > Preferences > Animation > F-Curves > Default Interpolation* and choose *Linear*.